# Setting-up a live ASP website

Tags: asp.net, azure-storage, web-hosting, vps

So, I've been setting my sights on MS Azure for quite awhile as my top hosting choice. I have a trial account and since I am still in the development phase of my ASP project, I wouldn't want to have to spent a cent yet.

However after a month, the issue of how I am going to host my website came into mind. I haven't tried Azure yet, however assuming I want to host it privately or using a VPS to save costs, how exactly do I transition my project for hosting?

Azure has a toolkit which handles the uploading and whatnot for me, however if I engage in VPS services, how do I set-up my website and will the cost difference be something worth looking at?

Comment: Classic ASP or ASP.NET?

Comment: @ShadowWizard ASP.NET

Comment: Why not using shared hosting? Or I would recommend you to use Cloud hosting, it is new technology. :)

Comment: Please tag properly then, did it for you this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot depends on what your needs are. "Hosting an ASP.Net website" covers a pretty broad spectrum from a simple one-page site that no one but you and a couple friends look at to a complex and highly trafficked site like StackOverflow. Telling you what you need to do to host your site is impossible without more details. However, to get you started with some basic information so that you can ask a better question I recommend you start with [this page](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/fundamentals/intro-to-windows-azure/), scroll down to the paragraphs labelled "Web Sites" and "Cloud Services".